# Dynamically adding data between pages in Flutter

Tags: flutter, dart

**FIRST PAGE**

So I have this ListTile that I would like to send to another page, let's call it 'Cart' page for demonstration purposes. It is in a separate function on the first page, above the builder and called in the builder later as a function. Here is the code of it:

```
return ListTile(
                  trailing: Container(
                    padding: EdgeInsets.only(top: 15.0),
                    child: IconButton(
                        icon: Icon(Icons.add),
                       
                        onPressed: () => MaterialPageRoute(
                              this i am not sure how to access cart page
                              builder: (context) =>
                                  Cart(food.name, food.price),
                            )),
                  ),
```

Notice how there is no Navigator.push() on the onPressed, because I just want data to be sent to the Cart page.

This is the function to send the data to the 'Cart' screen on another page and it works. The issue I have is that I want also to have a button on the AppBar (below in the builder) that just goes to that page without passing any data (the icon above should only pass data onPressed, it's the ListTile item on the first page.)

Here's the code for the AppBar icon on the first page:

```
return Scaffold( 
appBar: AppBar(
        actions: [
          IconButton(
            icon: Icon(Icons.add_shopping_cart, color: Colors.white),
           
            onPressed: () => print('This needs to lead to cart page.'),
            //I tried doing the Navigator.push route, but it asks for arguments, but I just want
            //to go to the page and not pass any arguments from here
            //this needs to lead to cart page
          ),
        ],)
```

**Cart page**

This is the 'Cart' page where the data should be pushed, ideally I would just want that ListTile item to be added to the Cart as the list tile same as the one on page 1.

```
 class Cart extends StatefulWidget {
  
  
  final String foodName;
  final String foodPrice;
  Cart(this.foodName, this.foodPrice);

  @override
  _CartState createState() => _CartState();
}

class _CartState extends State<Cart> {
  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return Scaffold(
      appBar: AppBar(
        title: Text('Cart'),
        centerTitle: true,
      ),
      body: Center(
          child: Container(
              child: Text('${widget.foodName}, ${widget.foodPrice}'))),
    );
  }
}
```

The problem is that I want to have different options for foods and sometimes add for example 'food.description' or something like that or even a different class like 'drink.name'. Here is my fantastic Paint demonstration on the issue.

[image]

Comment: may, using local storage is a good choice for you..

Comment: You should create a Model class for cart and in cart page, you can use Name parameters Cart({this.foodName, this.foodPrice}); .

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You should use a state managment package to that. Provider, Bloc , Redux etc. When user press Add button. You can add data to main source and notify listeners with these package. Here an example with Provider package:

```
import 'package:flutter/cupertino.dart';
import 'package:flutter/material.dart';
import 'package:provider/provider.dart';

class CartItemsModel extends ChangeNotifier {
  List<String> _cartItems = [];

  List<String> get cartItems => _cartItems;

  addCartItem(String item) {
    _cartItems.add(item);
    notifyListeners();
  }
}

class MainPage extends StatelessWidget {
  const MainPage({Key key}) : super(key: key);

  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return Provider(
      create: (c) => CartItemsModel(),
      child: MaterialApp(
        home: Consumer<CartItemsModel>(
          builder: (c, model, _) => Scaffold(
            appBar: AppBar(
              actions: [
                IconButton(
                  icon: Column(
                    children: [
                      Icon(Icons.add_shopping_cart_rounded),
                      Text('added items' + model.cartItems.length.toString()),
                    ],
                  ),
                  onPressed: () {
                    Navigator.of(context).push(MaterialPageRoute(
                      builder: (c) => SecondPage(),
                    ));
                  },
                ),
              ],
            ),
            body: Column(
              children: [
                Text('CartItems Length:' + model.cartItems.length.toString()),
                RaisedButton(
                  onPressed: () {
                    model.addCartItem('Example Cart Item');
                  },
                  child: Text('ADD ITEM'),
                ),
                RaisedButton(
                  onPressed: () {
                    Navigator.of(context).push(MaterialPageRoute(
                      builder: (c) => SecondPage(),
                    ));
                  },
                  child: Text('Go another page'),
                ),
              ],
            ),
          ),
        ),
      ),
    );
  }
}

class SecondPage extends StatelessWidget {
  const SecondPage({Key key}) : super(key: key);

  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return Consumer<CartItemsModel>(
      builder: (c, model, _) => Scaffold(
        body: Column(
          children: model.cartItems
              .map((e) => ListTile(
                    title: Text(e),
                  ))
              .toList(),
        ),
      ),
    );
  }
}
```

Run this app at your main function and see how it is working. When you press add item button it will add 'Example Cart Item' to list which is at provider class and provider class will notify other listener to update their state.
For more info:
https://pub.dev/packages/provider